# c# Regex problems

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this Regex which I'm working on

```
string addressstart = Regex.Escape("<a href=\"/url?q=");
                string addressend = Regex.Escape("&amp");
                string regAdd = addressstart + @"(.*?)" + addressend;
```

I'd like it to give me the url from this html

```
<a href="/url?q=https://www.google.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwizwPy0yNHSAhXMDpAKHec7DAsQFgh6MA0&amp;usg=AFQjCNEjJILXPMMCNAlz5MN1IIzjpr79tw">
```

so it should return "https://www.google.com/"

Any ideas Why it isnt working?
thanks!

Comment: Does my answer below help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex worked for me. Make sure that you select *group 1*, since *group 0* is always the full string.

```cs
@"<a href=\"\/url\?q=(.*?)&amp"
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try to use this though I get errors because of the quotation marks. Any Idea why this could be?

Answer (score 1):

As it appear you are looking for the url of google as part of your string.
You might find useful the following pattern which will match it:

```
https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}
```

It is to be noted this is a small tweak of the general regex found at: [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

**Edit** Please see the code below in order to apply this regex and find the value you are looking for:

```
string input = "<a href=\"/url?q=https://www.google.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwizwPy0yNHSAhXMDpAKHec7DAsQFgh6MA0&amp;usg=AFQjCNEjJILXPMMCNAlz5MN1IIzjpr79tw\">";
var regex = new Regex(@"https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}");
var output = regex.Match(input).Value; // https://www.google.com
```

Comment: If you are only matching the full thing then doing `https?:\/\/www\.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}` and choosing the group 0, will work too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `"<a href=\"/url?q="` part of the regular expression. The `?` is not escaped. It means an optional `l`. Hence that part of the regular expresion matches either `<a href="/urlq=` or `<a href="/urq=`. Neither include the `?` character.

Answer (score 0):

When parsing HTML, you should consider using some HTML parser, like HtmlAgilityPack, and only after getting the necessary node, apply the regex on the *plain* text.

If you want to debug your own code, here is a fix:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var s = "<a href=\"/url?q=https://www.google.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwizwPy0yNHSAhXMDpAKHec7DAsQFgh6MA0&amp;usg=AFQjCNEjJILXPMMCNAlz5MN1IIzjpr79tw\">";
        var pattern = @"<a href=""/url\?q=(.*?)&amp;";
        var result = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
        if (result.Success)
            Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

See a [DotNetFiddle demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hs0PiZ).

Here is an example how how you may extract all `<a>` *href* attribute values that start with `/url?q=` with [**HtmlAgilityPack**](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Install it via **Solution** > **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...** and use

```
public List<string> HapGetHrefs(string html)
{
    var hrefs = new List<string>();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hap;
    Uri uriResult;
    if (Uri.TryCreate(html, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
    { // html is a URL 
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
        hap = doc.Load(uriResult.AbsoluteUri);
    }
    else
    { // html is a string
        hap = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        hap.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    var nodes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[starts-with(@href, '/url?q=')]");
    if (nodes != null)
    {
       foreach (var node in nodes)
       {
           foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes)
               if (attribute.Name == "href")
               {
                   hrefs.Add(attribute.Value);
               }
        }
    }
    return hrefs;
 }
```

Then, all you need is apply a simpler regex or a couple of simpler string operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```regex
(?<=a href="\/url\?q=)[^&]+
```

Comment: What are the benefits to this approach over the accepted answer from two years ago?